# No data from view sys.resource_usage and sys.resource_stats in azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

When i run the following query in the Azure, I am getting no records. and getting the message "Query succeeded: Affected rows: 0."

```
1) SELECT * FROM sys.resource_usage where database_name='DB_NAME';
```

When i run this following query in azure, i get this error , "Failed to execute query. Error: Invalid object name 'sys.resource_stats'."

```
2) SELECT * FROM sys.resource_st where database_name='DB_NAME';
```

Please help me solve this issue, as im trying to track the daily database usage i.e amount of data stored in DB.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the issue is with your current db context, what does **SELECT DB_NAME()** return? Is that a user database? As per BOL '***This view is available to all user roles with permissions to connect to the virtual master database.***' you'd have to connect to the master database before query against both [sys.resource_usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-resource-usage-azure-sql-database) and [sys.resource_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-resource-stats-azure-sql-database).

Answer (score 0):

As Lin mentioned ,You have to connect to Master database to see output of `sys.resource_stats`

For DBspecific DTU usage , you can use  <kbd>[sys.dm_db_resource_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-resource-stats-azure-sql-database)</kbd> ..this stores data for every 15 seconds

and your question says

> as im trying to track the daily database usage i.e amount of data stored in DB.

you can use below DMV to track that

```
SELECT sys.objects.name, SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats, sys.objects
WHERE sys.dm_db_partition_stats.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
GROUP BY sys.objects.name;
GO
```